# how to stop showing listitle when data is empty on firestore firebase flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to hide a `listtitle` when its value is empty I'm using firestore. I don't if I should be using `listview.builder`

[image]

This my code:

```
Container( 
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 24.0),
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.35,
      child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            child: Card(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(widget.info.data()['test']),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            child: Card(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(widget.info.data()['test1']),
                subtitle: Text(widget.info.data()['test2']),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
        
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an if statement before the Container holding your `ListTile` to check if `widget.info.data() != null`

Comment: hi thanks for the fast replay but can you add the code to do so I'm new to flutter and coding

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use `ListView.Builder`it is more efficient in your case.

I have used ternary operator to deal with a null value, below code simply means if data is not null then ListTile will be building otherwise SizedBox of height 0.

```
 ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: widget.info.data().length,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return widget.info.data()!=null?ListTile(
                       title: Text(widget.info.data()['test1']),
                       subtitle: Text(widget.info.data()['test2']),
                      ):SizedBox(height:0.0);
                    }),
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply but can i put multiple listtitles inside a listview.builder??

Comment: No, you can return only one but if you want specific listtiles different from another than you can write if else statemnet for building particular indexes  after return statement